# performance issue in retrieving data from a varbinary field in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, binary-data

I am trying to retrieve data from a varbinary(max) field from a table which has about half a million records.
selecting even 1000 records is taking more than 3 to 4 minutes.I have removed that column and then it returns in seconds.
So, any help on available methods in sql to retrieve data from a varbinary(max) field would be helpful for me. Please let me know.

Comment: Please explain with examples

Comment: Also, post the Execution plan when you are running your queries against your `varbinary(max)` column

Comment: Additional Note: It is a good practice to store `varbinary` data in a separate Table.